# R: In a data frame, I get an error using a factor variable's level

Tags: r

This works as expected:

```
> sizes <- factor(c(1,2,3,7,9,2,1,3,7,3,9,2,3), levels = c(1,3,2,7,9),ordered=TRUE)
> sizes[2]
[1] 2
Levels: 1 < 3 < 2 < 7 < 9
> x=sizes[3]>sizes[2]
> x
[1] FALSE
```

When "sizes" is a column in a data frame, which is loaded using read.csv(), I get this error:

```
> A_Dataset <- read_csv("A_Dataset.csv", 
+     col_types = cols(A = col_integer(), 
+         B = col_integer(), sizes = col_factor(levels = c("1", 
+             "3", "2", "7", "9"))))
> A_Dataset$sizes = factor(A_Dataset$sizes, levels=c(1,3,2,7,9),ordered=TRUE)
> is.ordered(Week1_Dataset$sizes)
[1] TRUE
> x=A_Dataset[2,3]>Week1_Dataset[1,3]
Warning message:
In Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘>’ not meaningful for factors
```

How do I mathematically compare the values of sizes (by level) in a data frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is that you are comparing a tibble with a tibble. Suggestion is read [hadley wickham's R book](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/subsetting.html#subset-multiple), where it's written:

> Subsetting a tibble with [ always returns a tibble:

We can try an example:

```
sizes <- factor(c(1,2,3,7,9,2,1,3,7,3,9,2,3), levels = c(1,3,2,7,9),ordered=TRUE)
write.csv(data.frame(A=1:length(sizes),sizes=sizes),"test.csv",row.names=FALSE)

A_Dataset <- read_csv("test.csv", 
     col_types = cols(A = col_integer(), 
         sizes = col_factor(levels = c("1","3", "2", "7", "9"))))
A_Dataset$sizes = factor(A_Dataset$sizes, levels=c(1,3,2,7,9),ordered=TRUE)
```

If you look at the class:

```
class(A_Dataset[1,2])
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

You cannot compare the data.frames, you can do:

```
class(A_Dataset$sizes[2])
[1] "ordered" "factor"

A_Dataset$sizes[2] > A_Dataset$sizes[1]
[1] TRUE
```

And this works:

```
as.data.frame(A_Dataset[2,2]) >as.data.frame(A_Dataset[1,2])
     sizes
[1,]  TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks.  That's works.  I also wanted to get a good book about R, so I'll be reading your suggestion.